# Not able to use 'copy_perm' option in Net::SFTP::Foreign module's put()

Tags: perl, sftp

When i run:

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(transport => $conn
                                     ,timeout => $opt->{Timeout});

if ($sftp->put("$srcDirectory/$_", "$self->{remoteDir}/$tgtFile") { }
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't setstat remote file (setstat)': Operation
unsupported
```

So after doing some research i came to conclusion that i need to:

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(transport => $conn
                                     ,timeout => $opt->{Timeout});

$sftp->put("$srcDirectory/$_", "$self->{remoteDir}/$tgtFile",
             copy_perm => 0, copy_time => 0);
```

However now i get error:

```
`invalid option(s) 'copy_perm' at <my file name> line 281.`
```

This line 281 is wherei have the above put() call.

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong? Is copy_perm deprecated? It doesn't complain about copy_time is thats the only new argument i send.

Comment: What version of Net::SFTP::Foreign are you using? Why do you even use Net::SFTP::Foreign? Why not the native Net::SFTP?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: [Net::SFTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP) is unmaintained (last release was in 2005) and has lots of issues.

Comment: @Akb: your example works for me, and looking at the module code I can't see a way that error could happen unless you were using a quite old version of the module or a modified one.